# Media files not showing in API with Strapi

Tags: strapi

I have created a component with a media field. When I upload an image/video I can’t see it in the API. I’ve even tried using `?populate=*`.
What can I be missing?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `populate=*` give’s you the first level of relations so you get only component, but not the relation included in component.

I’m not sure what is your model looks like, what would give some more info how to properly write query, you have two options:

The easiest solution is:
`yarn add strapi-plugin-populate-deep`
`/api/pages/1?populate=deep`

harder one is to use `qs` with something like:

```
const str = qs.stringify(
  {
    populate: { hero: { populate: ["media", "heroImage"] } }
  },
  { encodeValuesOnly: true }
);
```

witch would give you:

```
populate[hero][populate][0]=media&populate[hero][populate][1]=heroImage
```

Comment: Thanks @antokhio. I used qs and it's working great!